# Facebook Ad with multiple images with Facebook marketing API

Tags: javascript, facebook, carousel, ads, facebook-marketing-api

I am using the facebook's marketting API to create the ad. I have successfully created the ad with a single image but now my requirement is to create the ad with multiple images. I am not sure how to create this.

I am working in ASP.NET MVC with C#. I tried to find the c# SDK from the facebook and also had found one but the APIs used in that were too old and facebook was not accepting any API request from that.

Then started to follow the facebook guide to use the graph API and the marketting API instructions. I created one page with the help of these links in javascript and html5 and all is working fine. But now stucked on creating the ad with multiple images.

Please anybody give the idea, how can I implement this. My working code is:

=============================================================================

```
function CarrouselCreative(images, actID, adSetID, campID, callback) {

    var apiURL = "/" + actID + "/adcreatives";
    var adCreativeName = $("#hdnCreativeName").val() + "-Creative";
    var adCreativeTitle = $("#txtCreativeAdTitle").val();
    var adCreativeBody = $("#txtAdBodyMessage").val();
    var imageURL = "http://www.test.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/maplegrove.jpeg";

    var url1 = encodeURI("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtkBB90ZG2Sk_MaNIvlz9pszpi9JJFnU38ol4Ac-NoDCuX3kGY");
    var url2 = encodeURI("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrGNQ5PLrhha-T9DAInIw0RtzqfyJUasP1Q-jfrt0nOJ2-qxe6");
    var url3 = encodeURI("http://www.test.com");


    var object_story = {
        "page_id": "18105454546788 ",
        "link ": "http: //www.test.com",
        "link_data": {
            "caption": "My caption",
            "child_attachments": [{
                "description": "$8.99",
                "image_hash": "2423690a56e826ce4af",
                "link": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtkBB90ZG2Sk_MaNIvlz9pszpi9JJFnU38ol4Ac-NoDCuX3kGY",
                "name": "Product 1",
                "object_type": "PHOTO"
            }, {
                "description": "$9.99",
                "image_hash": "4ff9caa3f714c8096ee",
                "link": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrGNQ5PLrhha-T9DAInIw0RtzqfyJUasP1Q-jfrt0nOJ2-qxe6",
                "name": "Product 2",
                "object_type": "PHOTO"
            }]
        }
    }
    debugger; 
    var story = JSON.stringify(object_story);
    FB.api(apiURL, 'POST', {
        name: adCreativeName,
        title: adCreativeTitle,
        body: adCreativeBody,
        object_story_spec: story
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
            alert("creativeID: " + response.error.error_user_title + " : " + response.error.error_user_msg);
            FB.api(campID, 'DELETE');
        }
        else {
            callback(response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

==================================================================
I need to add the details related to the following error message. 
"Your ad must contain feature one of the following: photo, video, link, template link, text or offer. Please add one of these assets and try again."

Here I need to make changes.......

```
var object_story = {
        "page_id": "18105454546788 ",
        "link ": "http: //www.test.com",
        "link_data": {
            "caption": "My caption",
            "child_attachments": [{
                "description": "$8.99",
                "image_hash": "2423690a56e826ce4af",
                "link": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtkBB90ZG2Sk_MaNIvlz9pszpi9JJFnU38ol4Ac-NoDCuX3kGY",
                "name": "Product 1",
                "object_type": "PHOTO"
            }, {
                "description": "$9.99",
                "image_hash": "4ff9caa3f714c8096ee",
                "link": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrGNQ5PLrhha-T9DAInIw0RtzqfyJUasP1Q-jfrt0nOJ2-qxe6",
                "name": "Product 2",
                "object_type": "PHOTO"
            }]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem I resolved by using the Python Ads API in my C# code. Facebook provides the full guidelines to create all kinds of ads including the carousal ad means ad with multiple images.

So recreated the complete code using the Python script and implemented that in C#. Now my ads application running smoothly.